# Creating Netbeans PHP project with existing sources on OS X

Tags: php, macos, netbeans

I need to debug an application that is currently on my local web server. The problem is that when I try to create a PHP application with existing sources and click "Browse" on "Sources Folder", Netbeans appears to not find/recognize my folders. For example, my application is in Applications/Xampp/htdocs/AppName, but NetBeans see my Applications folder empty.

I am using Netbeans 7.3.1 on OS X 10.8.4

Comment: See if your source folder have the same permissions as the netbeans.

Comment: You have to create a project then copy your existing file over